# Moving woocommerce shortdescription

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

im new at wordpress, and im trying to move the blocks from the product page details of woocommerce. In my situation im trying to move the short_description block after the add button, but isnt working.

Here my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'woocommerce_short_description');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`woocommerce_short_description` is a filter, not a function that loads the short description template. The function that you want is `woocommerce_template_single_excerpt`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt' );
```